# How can I import external JavaScript file?

Tags: tapestry

I need to import a JS file that is hosted on another server and is not part of my application's assets.

How can I import it from within the component?

Comment: for efficiency and reliability, i would strongly recommend downloading the script and hosting it from your application or web server.

Comment: The script is generted dynamically by external server so there is no way I can host it myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up setting up environmental `JavaScriptSupport` and calling `importJavaScriptLibrary` from within `setupRender()`:

```
@Environmental
private JavaScriptSupport javaScriptSupport;

public void setupRender() {
    this.javaScriptSupport.importJavaScriptLibrary("URL-to-JS-file");
}
```